# How can I do a reverse of json_decode(json_encode($), true)?

Tags: php, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, stdclass

I have an array of objects, where I have an array with stdClass Object, here is ok, next I show a snipplet of array

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 5384
            [post_title] => Accordeon me con jQuery
            [post_name] => accordeon-con-jquery
            [readings] => 55140
            [post_date] => 01-12-2012
            [media] => 59.546436285097
            [dias] => 926
        )
 
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2509
            [post_title] => Popup me con jQuery
            [post_name] => popup-me-con-jquery
            [readings] => 26261
            [post_date] => 13-04-2012
            [media] => 22.677892918826
            [dias] => 1158
        )
        ...
```

Next I need convert to array multidimensional, I use this to get an array multidimensional

```
$visits = json_decode(json_encode($visits), true);
```

And I get this, and here is ok

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 5384
            [post_title] => Accordeon me con jQuery
            [post_name] => accordeon-con-jquery
            [readings] => 55140
            [post_date] => 01-12-2012
            [media] => 59.546436285097
            [dias] => 926
        )
 
    [1] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 2509
            [post_title] => Popup me con jQuery
            [post_name] => popup-me-con-jquery
            [readings] => 26261
            [post_date] => 13-04-2012
            [media] => 22.677892918826
            [dias] => 1158
        )
        ...
```

So I need again an array of objects, so I use this

```
$visits = json_decode(json_encode($visits));
```

but I get an unexpected result, I get

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 5384
            [post_title] => Accordeon me con jQuery
            [post_name] => accordeon-con-jquery
            [readings] => 55140
            [post_date] => 01-12-2012
            [media] => 59.546436285097
            [dias] => 926
        )
 
    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 2509
            [post_title] => Popup me con jQuery
            [post_name] => popup-me-con-jquery
            [readings] => 26261
            [post_date] => 13-04-2012
            [media] => 22.677892918826
            [dias] => 1158
        )
        ...
```

What I can do to get again array - stdClass Object instead stdClass Object - stdClass Object?

Comment: What exactly is the difference between the first and last snippet?

Comment: @mousetail the first one's an array of objects, the last appears to be an object with numbered properties

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you have non-sequential keys in the array, which causes [`json_encode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode) to encode it as an object instead of an array (see example #4 on the [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode)). If you don't need to preserve the keys, you can simply use `array_values` on `$visits` first:

```
$visits = json_decode(json_encode(array_values($visits)));
```

If you need to preserve keys, then just cast the result to an array:

```
$visits = json_decode(json_encode($visits));
$visits = (array)$visits;
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/cCfeY)

Comment: [The fundamental goal of closing duplicate questions is to help people find the right answer by getting all of those answers in one place.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates#:~:text=The%20fundamental%20goal%20of%20closing%20duplicate%20questions%20is%20to%20help%20people%20find%20the%20right%20answer%20by%20getting%20all%20of%20those%20answers%20in%20one%20place.)